# Meteor - Cordova - Allow images from third party services and block other urls

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm trying to create an access rule that allows only links ending with an image extension. I've tried using this rule without success:

`App.accessRule('https://*.jpg', {type: 'intent'});`

The idea would be to include all possible image extensions but disallow any other link.

Also it would be nice to don't deny links ending with querystrings, such as

`[url].jpg?witdh=540&heigth=300`

is this possible to achieve?

Comment: `I've tried using this rule without success` how did this "without success" looked like?  Any errors? Maybe an https vs http issue on your webserver/proxy end?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** `App.accessRule` can only be used to **add** rules. So be sure that the existing rules are not already matching. (https://docs.meteor.com/api/mobile-config.html#App-accessRule)

**Note 2:** that the whitelist applies only to the main Cordova webview, and does not apply to an InAppBrowser webview or opening links in the system web browser. (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/appdev/whitelist/index.html#ios-whitelisting)

**Note 3:** We suggest you use a Content Security Policy (see below), which is more secure. This whitelist is mostly historical for webviews which do not support CSP. (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#network-request-whitelist)

So my recommendation would be going with CSP, e.g. allowing all images from https and self:

```
Content-Security-Policy: img-src https: 'self';
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src